# Efficient clean up

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> There is a chemical spill. $3$ crews are called in and asked to estimate how long it would take them to clean the spill if they worked on their own. The respective estimates were $46$, $51$, and $55$ days. If all three crews were hired and worked efficiently together, how long would it take for the clean up?

The only thing I can think of is $(46+51+55)/3$.

Is this correct? If not, can someone please explain how to think of the equation for these types of problems?

Comment: This is incorrect, you simply calculated the average speed of the three crews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crew 1 gets $\frac{1}{46}$ of the work done per day

Crew 2 gets $\frac{1}{51}$ of the work done per day

Crew 3 gets $\frac{1}{55}$ of the work done per day

So all together they get $\frac{1}{46}+\frac{1}{51}+\frac{1}{55}=\frac{7681}{129030}$ of the work done in a day.

So they will take $\frac{129030}{7681}\approx 16.8$ days to finish.

Comment: I understand the adding part, but why did you find the value of the reciprocal on the last step?

Comment: The work dones is the same as work/day* days spent. So we need work/day* days spent=1. So the days spent is the reciprocal of the works per day.

Comment: Check the case where they do half the job, so they take 2 days. If they do $\frac{2}{3}$ per day then they will require $\frac{3}{2}$ days

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way: what if each of the groups worked at the exact same rate? Then it would take $1/3$ of the time.

Now, for rates of $46$, $51$, $55$ by groups $1$, $2$, $3$, respectfully. Then the group that finishes in $46$ days will do more of the work than the other two; group $1$ will do $55/46$ more work than group $3$ and group $1$ will do $51/46$ more work than group $2$.

Let $x$ be the total work done by group $1$. Then

$$x + 55/46x + 51/46x = 1 = \text{total work}$$

Then $152/46x=1$, so $x=46/152$ is the work done by group $3$.